# How to change a label value at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html, events

The alert is showing, but the value is not changing.... why?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test EuDock</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <label id="labelID">test</label>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

            document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

            function KeyCheck(e) {

                var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

                switch(KeyID)
                {
                    case 39: // right arrow
                        document.getElementById('labelID').value="BLZ";
                        alert('ok');
                        break;
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only `input` elements have the property `value`. You want [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) :

```
document.getElementById('labelID').innerHTML="BLZ";
```

`innerHTML` is the only attribute that is [supported by all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03).

[`innerText` is not supported by Firefox](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04) and [`textContent` is not supported by <= IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07).

Comment: @Tom: Good that it works now :) Btw in German, BLZ is short for *Bankleitzahl* which means *bank identification number* :o)

Comment: I had the same problem as inthe question but when I use the innerHTML it dpesn't replace the text of the label it just appends the message I want in front of the allready placed text

Comment: @PaulLedger: Then maybe the text you want to replace is not part of the label/element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `value` is a property defined in the DOM for HTML elements.  Try assigning to `.innerHTML` instead, and I think you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById('labelID').innerText ="BLZ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The label element does not have a value property. use `document.getElementById('labelID').innerHTML="BLZ";` instead.

Comment: Ya, I realized as soon as I posted it. I was testing the same with Firebug at that time. :)